# SIMD __m256i to __m256d cast results

Tags: c++, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx2

I am trying to cast a SIMD integer variable into a double. But I can't see what the result of this operation will be.
Example:

```
int arr[8]={12345678,12333333,12344444,12355555,12366666,12377777,12388888,12399999};
__m256i temp = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *) arr);
__m256d temp2 = _mm256_castsi256_pd (temp);
```

as a result of this operation what are the members in my temp2?

Comment: Why are you using `_mm256_load_si256`, which may cause faults, instead of `_mm256_loadu_si256`?

Comment: i didn't know that would cause faults, i will change to _mm256_loadu_si256 next time.

Comment: That might cause fault but modern compilers are smart and they align it. BTW, in order to avoid segmentation fault you can align your array to 32-byte boundary with searching align google for your platform including OS and Compiler.

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

The members in `temp2` will be:

```
{4.014635e-305, 4.062922e-305, 4.111209e-305, 4.159495e-305}
```

## How to obtain the values

Just write the SIMD data into an `double` array back and print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main(void) {
    int hoge[4]; /* hack that worked on tested environment to avoid Segmentation Fault */
    double result[4];
    int i;

    int arr[8]={12345678,12333333,12344444,12355555,12366666,12377777,12388888,12399999};
    __m256i temp = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *) arr);
    __m256d temp2 = _mm256_castsi256_pd (temp);

    _mm256_storeu_pd(result, temp2);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) printf("result[%d] = %.6e (%.15a)\n", i, result[i], result[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

[I ran this code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eP47el7bVRhQK2Db) and got this output:

```
result[0] = 4.014635e-305 (0x1.c311500bc614e00p-1012)
result[1] = 4.062922e-305 (0x1.c87e300bc5c7c00p-1012)
result[2] = 4.111209e-305 (0x1.cdeb100bcb34a00p-1012)
result[3] = 4.159495e-305 (0x1.d357f00bd0a1800p-1012)
```

You can write the SIMD data to an `double` array via [`_mm256_storeu_pd()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_storeu_pd&expand=3311,3385,5549,5610,5610).

An exception may be generated when address that is not 32-byte aligned is passed into [`_mm256_load_si256()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_load_si256&expand=3385,5549,5610,5610,3311,3311), so you should do the alignment. Actually Segmentation Fault occurred on Wandbox, so I inserted the dummy array `hoge` to do the alignment.

## Why the values were obtained

[`_mm256_castsi256_pd()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_castsi256_pd%2520&expand=3385,5549,5610,5610,3311,3311,624) is actually just copying the bytes and changing their interpretation.

Assuming little-endian is used and `int` is 4-byte long,
the data in `arr` is like this in the byte-addressed memory:

```
data in arr[8]:
|   12345678|   12333333|   12344444|   12355555|   12366666|   12377777|   12388888|   12399999|
byte data in arr[8] (in little endian):
|4e 61 bc 00|15 31 bc 00|7c 5c bc 00|e3 87 bc 00|4a b3 bc 00|b1 de bc 00|18 0a bd 00|7f 35 bd 00|
data seen as 64-bit hex:
|     0x00bc311500bc614e|     0x00bc87e300bc5c7c|     0x00bcdeb100bcb34a|     0x00bd357f00bd0a18|
```

Then, assuming that 64-bit [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is used in `double`, the 64-bit data consists of 1-bit sign, 11-bit exponent and 52-bit significand.

Taking the first element `0x00bc311500bc614e` as example, the sign bit is `0` (plus/zero), the exponent is `0x00b` (11 - 1023 = -1012) and the significand is `0xc311500bc614e`.

This matches with what is printed via `%.15a` in the sample code above.
(two extra `0`s are printed because printing 15 digits is specified while only data for 13 digits is reordered, so the remainder is padded with `0`.)
The other elements also matches like this.

Comment: You don't need a dead-reckoning hack, just `alignas(32) double result[4];` if you want to use alignment-required `store` instead of `storeu`, to make sure you don't have a cache-line split.  Sometimes gcc will choose to over-align arrays that are the target of an aligned store, but I guess not always.

Comment: And BTW, we're talking about x86 intrinsics, so yes `int` is 4 bytes, `double` is IEEE binary64, and everything is little endian.  Intel's intrinsics API isn't careful about types, so it's only compatible with ABIs where this is true.  (Which of course includes all existing x86 / x86-64 ABIs.)

Answer (score 2):

As a result of this operation, temp2 will contain garbage. For example, the first double lane will be 4.0146351468550722e-305.

This is by design. `_mm256_castsi256_pd` intrinsic doesn’t convert values, it only re-interprets bits in register as doubles.

If you want these double constants in the register, just use `_mm256_setr_pd` intrinsic:

```
// Set double values to the constants
__m256d temp2 = _mm256_setr_pd( 12345678, 12333333, 12344444, 12355555 );
```

Or if these values aren’t constant, use _mm256_cvtepi32_pd intrinsic, here's a complete example:

```
alignas( 32 ) int arr[ 8 ] = { 12345678, 12333333, 12344444, 12355555,
    12366666, 12377777, 12388888, 12399999 };
__m256i integers = _mm256_load_si256( ( const __m256i* ) &arr );
// Convert first 4 int32 values to doubles
__m256d lowDoubles = _mm256_cvtepi32_pd( _mm256_castsi256_si128( integers ) );
// Convert last 4 values to doubles
__m256d highDoubles = _mm256_cvtepi32_pd( _mm256_extracti128_si256( integers, 1 ) );
```

This will actually convert, not bit cast, the values.

AVX registers hold 256 bits of data. This is 8 int32 values in `__m256i` type, 8 float values in `__m256` data type, but only 4 double values in `__m256d` type.

P.S. There’s also alignment bug in your code, best way to fix is add `alignas(32)` before `int arr[8]`

Comment: `__m256d temp2 = _mm256_cvtepi32_pd( temp );` when I run this I get the error `error: cannot convert ‘__m256i {aka __vector(4) long long int}’ to ‘__m128i {aka __vector(2) long long int}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__m256d _mm256_cvtepi32_pd(__m128i)’
   __m256d temp3 = _mm256_cvtepi32_pd( temp1 );` I think its because the function requires a __128i variable but temp1 is a __258i variable. Do you know a fast way to convert from __258i to __128i? So that I would only use the first 4 integers first and then the second 4

Comment: thank you very much that worked. One last question. when I store the integers as double with these simd functions, my values change from 12345678 to 1.23456... even though my value is not above 2^52 ( which when I looked up was the highest integer a double can store). Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe what if i explain what im trying to achieve it would make more sense. I am trying to do integer division in simd but since theres no function for it i am trying to first cast my integers to doubles and then do the divison and cast it back again. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar See another update, I’ve verified the registers contain correct numbers.

About division, the easy way is use Intel compiler, it has `_mm256_div_epi32` function implemented in its runtime library.

Yes, you can do with doubles if that’s what you need.

Comment: Also, if you know divisors in advance and they’re same across all lanes, there’s better way, use godbolt.org then manually translate from assembly to vector intrinsics. E.g. this is how to divide by 12345678: https://godbolt.org/z/bmMO3S `imul` -> `_mm256_mullo_epi32`, `sar` -> `_mm256_srai_epi32`, `shr` -> `_mm256_srli_epi32`, `add` -> `_mm256_add_epi32`.

Comment: @Soonts: or if you don't care about MSVC, you can use GNU C native vector syntax to let gcc/clang/ICC emit the vector shifts for you, with `typedef int v8si __attribute__((vector_size(32)))`.  Then you can do `v8si v=a __m256i var;  v /= 123;`  See for example [What's the fastest way to generate a 1 GB text file containing random digits?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/324520) where I used this for `/` and `%` by 10 in `vec_store_digit_and_space()`.

Comment: And BTW, you'd probably be better off with two 128-bit loads to feed the two `vcvtdq2pd` instructions, so they could just use memory source operands.  That's 1 micro-fused uop on Skylake, but the XMM->YMM version is 2 uops (shuffle + FMA port to line up the integer inputs with the double outputs).  https://agner.org/optimize/ The load port can shuffle sufficiently for free, so you definitely want to hint the compiler into doing it that way unless surrounding code is totally bottlenecked on port 2/3 throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Operation `_mm256_castsi256_pd` does literally nothing, it is a reinterpretation - equivalent to:

```
  int v_i;
  double d_i = *((double*)(int*)&v_i).
```

Use `__m256d _mm256_cvtepi32_pd (__m128i a)` as it actually converts 4 integers to 4 doubles.

```
alignas(16) int arr[4]={12345678,12333333,12344444,12355555};
__m128i temp = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *) arr);
__m256d temp2 = _mm256_cvtepi32_pd(temp);
```

Note: the loading operations `_mm_load_si128` and `_mm256_load_si256` require the addresses to be properly aligned. Else use the unaligned versions `_mm_loadu_si128` and `_mm256_loadu_si256`; thought the unaligned versions are slower.

Comment: Equivalent except without any undefined behaviour from violating strict aliasing.  Also `int` and `double` aren't the same size on any x86 C++ implementation.  `memcpy` from `double` to `uint64_t` would be a better example.

Comment: `__m256d temp2 = _mm256_cvtepi32_pd(temp);` Is there  a way to fastly split an __m256i variable into 2 __m128i variables so that I can use it in this function?

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar: [`_mm256_extracti128_si256`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&expand=2424,6150,6150,401,2424&text=vextracti1) for the high half (1 shuffle instruction), and `_mm256_castsi256_si128` the low half (zero instructions).